# Angular - How to use a regex on a formControl

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an input form in angular

```
 <input matInput
   formControlName="eventDate" [max]="utilService.getToday()"
   [matDatetimepicker]="datetimePicker"
   required
   autocomplete="false">
```

Since the input is a `date`
What I want to do is, subscribe to the valueChanges of the form and whenever the user insert a value, check if it is a valid format with the regular expression and only then validate the `if`  statement.

This is what I'm trying to do, but it is not checking the regex:

```
this.inputFormGroup.get('eventDate').valueChanges.subscribe(
      (selectedValue) => {
        const re = new RegExp('[0-9]{1,2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{1,2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{4}');
        const result = re.exec(selectedValue);
        
        if(result !== null) {
          console.log('do my stuff');
        }
      }
    );
```

Comment: `but it is not checking the regex` what's that mean?, it's not run into your callback your stuck somewhere?

Comment: it is not going into the 'if' statement even if I insert an input that satisfies the regex. It's like the regex is not being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Validators.pattern`.
For example, declare your url pattern

```
 const urlRegex = /'[0-9]{1,2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{1,2}(/|-|.)[0-9]{4}'/
```

then on your formgroup, simply do this

```
...
eventDate = new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern(urlRegex)]);
```

Comment: seems he's not trying to validate the form, but want to do something if the input match some specific pattern, am I right?

Comment: The above will do the same I believe. He can then do ```if (eventDate.valid){ //do something}```